# Is there a function for plotting a heading (360) direction from a GPS point in matplotlib/basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gps, matplotlib-basemap

I have to create a plot of a vessel underwater in the ocean. I have GPS data and heading data. The data set is in a pandas data frame. I want to plot the heading of the vehicle as an arrow coming off the main GPS line.

[image]

This image is my GPS heading. I wanted to do this in basemap but I cant seem to even figure out how to do this is matplotlib. I have bee searching for days and cant figure it out. below i have an example of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap



data = pd.read_csv('dataset')
style.use('seaborn')

data['pd_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time (UTC)'])
       # convert current date format into pandas date time format 

gpsdata = data.loc[:, ['m_gps_lon (DDMM.MMMM)', 'm_gps_lat (DDMM.MMMM)']] #from my data set
gpsdata = gpsdata.dropna() 
plt.plot(gpsdata['m_gps_lon (DDMM.MMMM)'], gpsdata['m_gps_lat (DDMM.MMMM)'], '-.')
plt.title('GPS')
plt.xlabel('lon')
plt.ylabel('lat')
plt.show()

place = 'some area'
c = {'llclon': -55, 'llclat': 55, 'urclon': 55, 'urclat': 55}
map = Basemap(
    llcrnrlon= c['llclon'], llcrnrlat= c['llclat'],
    urcrnrlon= c['urclon'], urcrnrlat= c['urclat'], 
    resolution='l')
    #projections: cyl=cylindrical equidistant projection, ortho=orthographic
map.drawcoastlines()

plt.plot(gpsdata['m_gps_lon (DDMM.MMMM)'], gpsdata['m_gps_lat (DDMM.MMMM)'], '-.')
plt.plot(data['pd_datetime'], np.rad2deg(data['m_heading (rad)']), '.', color='red') #i thought this would at least plot a point. but it doesnt do anything. all headings are in compass headings. not nessisarily pointing in the direction of the track
plt.show()
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you want a "quiver plot"

Comment: I tried quiver plot, but correct me if i am wrong, I thought quiver(x,y,u,v) the u and v are combined. and it works well with water current in the x and y direction.

Comment: That is correct, but if you have the bearing, you can easily compute the u & v

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to work. I used a math function to post a new position using heading and an arbitrary distance, just to visualize the heading.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dec = np.deg2rad(22.74)         #NOAA declination correction for area 
R = 6378.1                      #Radius of the Earth
brng = np.deg2rad(320) - dec    #bearing needs to be in rad 
d = 1                           #Distance in km, this didn't matter to me. 1 km is arbitrary, but it could matter to you. 

### c_heading
heading_lat1 = np.deg2rad(pandas_df['dataframe header latitude (DD.DDDD)'])
heading_lon1 = np.deg2rad(pandas_df['dataframe header longitude (DD.DDDD)'])

heading_lat2 = np.arcsin(np.sin(heading_lat1)*np.cos(d/R) + np.cos(heading_lat1)*np.sin(d/R)*np.cos(brng)) 
heading_lon2 = heading_lon1 + np.arctan2(np.sin(brng)*np.sin(d/R)*np.cos(heading_lat1), 
        np.cos(d/R) - np.sin(heading_lat1)*np.sin(heading_lat2))

heading_lat2 = np.rad2deg(heading_lat2)
heading_lon2 = np.rad2deg(heading_lon2)
```

Note that I was using a `pandas dataframe`, and this will work with `import math` and math functions. But from my experience so far, math does not play well with pandas dataframe

Hope This helps someone